# Loaded Dice Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayes-theorem

If I have two dice, one regular and one loaded. The loaded die has the probability 1/2 of landing a six and rest of the numbers are equally probable. If you select a die randomly and throw it and it shows 6 in one of the throws and not a six in other. What is the probability of having a weighted die?

[My approach:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNHCb.jpg)

Is this correct or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Probability of having the weighted die. Sorry, I edited the question.

Comment: The denominator is a bit smudgy. If the second term is $(1/2)(10/36)$ it is right.

Comment: It looks good (though your definition of $B$ isn't quite right).

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Yes it is $(1/2)(10/36)$. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidMitra: Should $B$ be getting six in one of the throws?

Comment: In only one of the throws.

Answer (score 1):

Let's denote the events

LD - picked up the loaded dice;

S - shows 6 in the 1st throw and not 6 on the second throw;

We are asked to find
$$
P(LD|S)
$$
Use Bayesian theorem
$$
P(LD|S) = \frac{P(S|LD)P(LD)}{P(S|LD)P(LD) + P(S|\overline{LD})P(\overline{LD})}
$$
where
$$P(S|LD) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2},~P(LD)=P(\overline{LD})=\frac{1}{2},~P(S|\overline{LD}) = \frac{1}{6}\frac{5}{6}
$$
plug all back to the fraction, I got
$$
\frac{9}{14}
$$